# Parallel code for matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I want to run the code for matrix multiplication in parallel in Matlab. I have written the sequential code for it. I have used 'spmd' method to run it in parallel. But, execution time of parallel code is more than the sequential code. My motto is to reduce the execution time my running the code in parallel.
I don want to use Inbuilt functions for multiplication, as i want to remove the dependency in for loops and run it. how can i do it?? 
I have tried fallowing code..
Please help me out..

```
a=[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,0;8,9,10,11;12,13,14,15];
b=[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,0;8,9,10,11;12,13,14,15];
warning off all;      
%Sequential code
tic
  for i=1:4
  for j=1:4
       sum=0;
       for k=1:4
           sum=sum+(a(i,k)*b(k,j));
       c(i,j)=sum;
       end;
  end;
  end;
  time1 =toc

  %parallel code
  matlabpool('open');
tic
spmd
for i=1:4
  for j=1:4
       sum=0;
       for k=1:4
           sum=sum+(a(i,k)*b(k,j));
       c(i,j)=sum;
       end;
  end;
  end;
 end;
time2 =toc
```

The output i got was.. time1 for sequencial and time2 for parallel

> > matrix

```
time1 =

0.0041

Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... connected to 2 labs.

time2 =

0.6950

>>
```

Comment: try to put the tic after spmd

Comment: You're unlikely to see any improvement for such a trivial example: you should try setting `a` and `b` to be, e.g., `10000x10000` matrces. This, however, will still most likely be slower to do in parallel - the BLAS algorithms that underpin MATLAB are very fast. By the way, your reason for doing this (which I interpret as "removing dependencies" from your question) is rather shaky... There are many more dependencies for the parallel computing toolbox than there are for simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: I tried with putting tic after SPMD, it dint work

Comment: I tried with large matrices too.. it dint work, actually i want to run ART algorithm in parallel. To begin with learning the parallel processing, i started with matrix multiplication so Please help me with some links,or references.

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment rather than an answer:

- Your test matrices are very small; any possible speed-up in execution will be overwhelmed by the overhead of starting a parallel execution pool;
- You don't seem to initialise your output matrix `c`; creating a matrix dynamically as your code suggests is known to be much slower than updating a previously-created matrix.  Try `c = zeros(grows,ncols)` to start with.
- I believe that recent editions of Matlab will automatically multi-thread straightforward matrix multiplications, you face a real challenge trying to write a function of your own which matches the native approach for speed.

Comment: Correct - explicit parallelisation using an SPMD block (on a single machine) is never ever going to beat MATLAB's implicit multithreading (nor should it).

Comment: My motto is to run ART sequential algorithm in parallel, to begin with parallel processing i just doing with matrix multiplication. so i want to learn how can i remove dependencies in for loops.